# In Python I'd like to make a code to show the following table from a double array

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, alignment

I'd like to make a code to obtain the following result.

```
Input: mylist=[[-1,3,111,'b'],[0,'a',1],[-2,1]]
Output:  -1         111    'b'
          3   'a'    1
         -2    1
```

I tried to make the code as follows.

```
blank1=' '
for x in mylist:
    for y in x:
         print blank1 if y==0 else y,
    print
print
```

But the result is not what I want. 
I'd like to make each entry align to center 
Where should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.center

```
for x in mylist:
    s=""
    for y in x:
        s+=str(" " if y==0 else y).center(10)
    print s
```

Change 10 to whatever width you want.

If you really want those qoutes you can use this:

```
s+=str(" " if y==0 else "'"+y+"'" if isinstance(y, basestring) else y).center(10)
```

Output of this code with the quote twitch using your array:

```
-1                 111       'b'    
         'a'        1     
-2        1
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to make each letter align to right?

Comment: Honestly, you should start looking a bit in the documentation on your own. The fact that str.center() exists makes it pretty likely that a similar function exists. And yes, it's called rjust. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm